# Monogame pipeline is throws exceptions when trying to build .tmx files

Tags: monogame, monogame-extended

I have correct referenced the monogame extended pipeline dll file to the monogame pipeline
the importers and processors of the .tmx file are not missing/unknown
but when I try to build the it it throws a System.notSupportedException
Here's a screenshot if that helps

[image]

Comment: "The given path's format is not supported" - what is the full path to this file?

Comment: D:/Project/Gamesmonogame/lion/Content/Map.tmx

Comment: [Looks like there's some discussion of a similar error here](https://community.monogame.net/t/monofoxe/11646)